# Recorrer Json Array de 4 niveles o mas Java (android)

Tags: java, android-studio, json

Tengo un `JSON` que tiene 4 objetos JSON, mi pregunta es como recorrerlo de tal manera que con primero hacer una cosa con el segundo otra y así sucesivamente
he probado con:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
  for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {                                   
    JSONObject row = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    String pasi =row.getString("nombre");
    }
```

Pero solo me recorre si recibe un objeto de JSON, el problema es que debe recibir uno de 4 niveles (4 array dentro de uno solo)

El json recibido es el siguiente:

```
{
"paises": [
    {
        "id": "68",
        "nombre": "El Salvador",
        "activo": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "70",
        "nombre": "Eritrea",
        "activo": "0"
    }
],
"procedencia": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nombre": "Establecimiento"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nombre": "Colvol"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nombre": "Promotor Antimalaria"
    }
],
"clave": [
    {
        "id": "2",
        "id_departamento": "11",
        "id_municipio": "185",
        "correlativo": "40",
        "clave": "11-40"
    }
],
"departamento": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nombre": "Ahuachapán",
        "id_pais": "68"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nombre": "Santa Ana",
        "id_pais": "68"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres acceder a todos los valores dentro de cualquiera de los Arrays.

Para contestar tu pregunta usare uno de los arrays. En este caso el de paises. Digamos que quiero obtener el nombre del segundo objeto, "Eritrea".

En este caso primero que nada debes tener un JsonObject que contenga todo tu JSON, es decir tus 4 arrays. Una vez hayas echo eso debes crear un JsonArray. Como voy a accesar a la información del Array de paises hare lo siguiente:

```
JsonObject tuJson; //Ya debe estar inicializado
JsonArray paises = tuJson.getJsonArray("paises");
```

Una vez hecho esto el JsonArray de paises contiene lo siguiente:

```
{"paises":[{"id":"68","nombre":"El Salvador","activo":"1"},{"id":"70","nombre":"Eritrea","activo":"0"}]
```

Y de ahora en adelante funciona como un Array cualquiera. El index 0 seria el primer objeto, es decir el objeto que tiene como "id" 68 y como "nombre" El salvador. Dije que quería accesar al segundo objeto y obtener su nombre "Eritrea", así que hago lo siguiente:

```
JsonObject segundo = paises.getJsonObject(1); //Segundo objeto, index 1
String nombre = segundo.getString("nombre"); //Nombre tendra como valor "Eritrea"
```

Tu dijiste que querías recorrerlo todo así que se vería algo asi:

```
for(int x = 0; x < paises.size(); x++){
   JsonObject elemento = paises.getJsonObject(x);
   int id = elemento.getInt("id");
   String nombre = elemento.getString("nombre");
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda y perdoname si malinterprete tu pregunta, no puedo comentar para pedir aclaraciones. El proceso es basicamente lo mismo para los 4 arrays.

Comment: perfecto me ha funcionado!! muchas gracias

Comment: Que bueno, me alegra poderte haber ayudado. Saludos.